Merging bars in bar plot using ggplot 2 in R
I have a data frame called df that has 3 likert scale levels columns and one filter column:
df
# A tibble: 50 × 4
   val1                   val2                   val3                var  
   <chr>                  <chr>                  <chr>               <chr>
 1 "Very \n Dissatisfied" "Neutral"              "Very \n Dissatisf… Yes  
 2 "Neutral"              "Neutral"              "Neutral"           No   
 3 "Dissatisfied"         "Satisfied"            "Neutral"           Yes  
 4 "Very \n Satisfied"    "Satisfied"            "Very \n Satisfied" Yes  
 5 "Very \n Dissatisfied" "Very \n Dissatisfied" "Neutral"           Yes  
 6 "Very \n Satisfied"    "Very \n Satisfied"    "Very \n Satisfied" Yes  
 7 "Dissatisfied"         "Neutral"              "Dissatisfied"      Yes  
 8 "Neutral"              "Satisfied"            "Neutral"           Yes  
 9 "Satisfied"            "Very \n Satisfied"    "Satisfied"         No   
10 "Neutral"              "Satisfied"            "Neutral"           Yes  


the resulting function from a previous question here
gives me the bar plot all the same value.Which is correct.!! All i want is instead of repeating it 3 times (20,30 and 50) i want to have it one time this bar of the right plot.Not 3 .
Is that possible ?
plot_fun <- function(x, y) {
  .data <- df |>
    filter(var %in% x)

  p1 <- .data |>
    ggstats::gglikert(include = -var) +
    aes(y = reorder(.question,
      ifelse(
        .answer %in% c("Very \n Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied"),
        1, 0
      ),
      FUN = sum
    ), decreasing = TRUE) +
     facet_wrap(~paste0("var to ", y))+ scale_fill_manual(values = custom_colors) +
       theme(
        strip.text = element_text(size = 14,color = "black"),               # Increase facet label size
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14),               # Increase axis title size
        axis.text = element_text(size = 10))+               # Increase axis text size
    theme(strip.background = element_rect(color="black", fill="red", size=1.5, linetype="solid"))

  p2 <- .data %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(-var) |>
    filter(!is.na(value)) |> 
    mutate(
      name = reorder(name,
        ifelse(
          value %in% c("Very \n Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied"),
          1, 0
        ),
        FUN = sum
      )
    ) |>
   ggplot(aes(y = name)) +
    geom_bar(fill = "lightgrey")+
    theme_light()+
    geom_text(aes(label = ..count..), 
              stat = "count",
              position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
      theme(
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank())

  
  list(p1, p2)
}

.include <- list(No = "No", Yes = "Yes", All = c("Yes", "No"))

purrr::imap(.include, plot_fun) |>
  purrr::reduce(c) |>
  wrap_plots(ncol = 2) +
  plot_layout(axes = "collect", guides = "collect", widths = c(.7, .3)) &
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) &
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

Data
 dput(df)
structure(list(val1 = c("Very \n Dissatisfied", "Neutral", "Dissatisfied", 
"Very \n Satisfied", "Very \n Dissatisfied", "Very \n Satisfied", 
"Dissatisfied", "Neutral", "Satisfied", "Neutral", "Very \n Dissatisfied", 
"Very \n Satisfied", "Very \n Dissatisfied", "Satisfied", "Neutral", 
"Very \n Dissatisfied", "Neutral", "Neutral", "Satisfied", "Neutral", 
"Very \n Satisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Satisfied", 
"Neutral", "Dissatisfied", "Satisfied", "Very \n Dissatisfied", 
"Dissatisfied", "Very \n Dissatisfied", "Very \n Dissatisfied", 
"Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Neutral", "Dissatisfied", 
"Dissatisfied", "Very \n Dissatisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", 
"Neutral", "Very \n Dissatisfied", "Very \n Satisfied", "Very \n Dissatisfied", 
"Satisfied", "Very \n Dissatisfied", "Very \n Dissatisfied", 
"Satisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied"), val2 = c("Neutral", 
"Neutral", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Very \n Dissatisfied", 
"Very \n Satisfied", "Neutral", "Satisfied", "Very \n Satisfied", 
"Satisfied", "Very \n Dissatisfied", "Very \n Satisfied", "Satisfied", 
"Very \n Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Neutral", "Dissatisfied", 
"Satisfied", "Neutral", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Neutral", 
"Very \n Satisfied", "Very \n Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", 
"Very \n Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Neutral", "Neutral", "Neutral", 
"Neutral", "Neutral", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Dissatisfied", 
"Neutral", "Satisfied", "Very \n Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", 
"Very \n Dissatisfied", "Satisfied", "Neutral", "Satisfied", 
"Very \n Dissatisfied", "Neutral", "Satisfied", "Neutral", "Satisfied"
), val3 = c("Very \n Dissatisfied", "Neutral", "Neutral", "Very \n Satisfied", 
"Neutral", "Very \n Satisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Neutral", "Satisfied", 
"Neutral", "Very \n Dissatisfied", "Very \n Satisfied", "Very \n Dissatisfied", 
"Satisfied", "Neutral", "Very \n Dissatisfied", "Satisfied", 
"Neutral", "Satisfied", "Neutral", "Very \n Satisfied", "Neutral", 
"Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Neutral", "Dissatisfied", "Satisfied", 
"Very \n Satisfied", "Neutral", "Very \n Dissatisfied", "Very \n Dissatisfied", 
"Dissatisfied", "Satisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", 
"Very \n Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Very \n Dissatisfied", 
"Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Neutral", "Very \n Dissatisfied", 
"Very \n Satisfied", "Very \n Dissatisfied", "Satisfied", "Very \n Dissatisfied", 
"Dissatisfied", "Satisfied", "Neutral", "Dissatisfied"), var = c("Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", 
"No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes"
)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
likert_levels <- c(
  "Strongly disagree",
  "Disagree",
  "Neither agree nor disagree",
  "Agree",
  "Strongly agree"
)




Note that the legend is wrong, ggplot is ordering alphabetically when it should be ordered by meaning. You can use factor or ordered to set the factor levels to the right order.

@RuiBarradas can you give it a try please?

Simply remove the pivoting part:
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

likert_levels <- c(
  "Very \n Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Neutral",
  "Satisfied", "Very \n Satisfied"
)

plot_fun <- function(x, y) {
  .data <- df |>
    filter(var %in% x) |>
    mutate(
      across(-var, ~ factor(.x, likert_levels))
    )

  p1 <- .data |>
    ggstats::gglikert(include = -var) +
    aes(y = reorder(.question,
      ifelse(
        .answer %in% c("Very \n Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied"),
        1, 0
      ),
      FUN = sum
    ), decreasing = TRUE) +
    facet_wrap(~ paste0("var to ", y)) +
    # scale_fill_manual(values = custom_colors) +
    theme(
      strip.text = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"), # Increase facet label size
      axis.title = element_text(size = 14), # Increase axis title size
      axis.text = element_text(size = 10)
    ) + # Increase axis text size
    theme(strip.background = element_rect(color = "black", fill = "red", size = 1.5, linetype = "solid"))

  p2 <- .data %>%
    count() |> 
    ggplot(aes(y = factor(1), x = n)) +
    geom_col(fill = "lightgrey") +
    theme_light() +
    geom_text(aes(label = n),
      position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)
    ) +
    theme(
      axis.text.y = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
    )

  list(p1, p2)
}

.include <- list(No = "No", Yes = "Yes", All = c("Yes", "No"))

purrr::imap(.include, plot_fun) |>
  purrr::reduce(c) |>
  wrap_plots(ncol = 2) +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect", widths = c(.7, .3)) &
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) &
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")


